# How to print a number of double type upto a single decimal place in C language?

Tags: c, types

This is what I'm trying to do:-

```
    double x = 4.0
    double y = 4.0
    x+y = 8.0
```

The input has to be of double type only (given condition of the problem).

Comment: Any [good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) would have told you that. Or a quick search in your favorite search engine.

Comment: Do suggest some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("%.1lf", yournumber);
```

will do the trick. This will print value to `1` decimal place. In case number is `1.123`, printed number will be rounded, in this case to `1.1`.